# call out method is not called in a continuous class, call out from VF page

Tags: callout, httprequest, continuation

I was trying to do a callout from a VF page constructor. I'm using `Continuation` class. As I've to show the response in the Page. Yhe problem is the callout method is not called.

Below is the code, I checked in the debug log the method `processResponse` never called.

```
public Object startRequest(string DocId) {
        Continuation con = new Continuation(40);
        con.continuationMethod='processResponse';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('URL');//end point URL
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         String body = CalloutHandler.getStatus(DocId);
        req.setBody(body);
        requestLabel = con.addHttpRequest(req);
        return con;  
    }
```

// Callback method

```
    public Object processResponse() { 
        HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(this.requestLabel);
        GetDrawingStatusResponse resp = New GetDrawingStatusResponse ();
        result = response.getBody();
        /*
To Do logic 

*/    
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of Continuation.

> A user invokes an action on a Visualforce page that requests
>   information from a Web service (step 1). The app server hands the
>   callout request to the Continuation server before returning to the
>   Visualforce page (steps 2–3). The Continuation server sends the
>   request to the Web service and receives the response (steps 4–7), then
>   hands the response back to the app server (step 8). Finally, the
>   response is returned to the Visualforce page (step 9).

[image]

The important bit to look is, **"A user invokes an action on a Visualforce page that requests information from a Web service"**

The constructor is not an Action. And as the continuation method is not called from an ACTION it won't execute.

If you still wanna make a callout on PAGE load, similar to the constructor, you can use "action" attribute of VF Page.

```
<apex:page action="{!doContinuationAction}">
Your Body
</apex:page>
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_overview.htm

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm

Comment: I've tried using Page action, still the callback method is not executing

Comment: Are there more than 2 methods with name "processResponse" ?

Comment: No, only one method named "processResponse"

Comment: can you try calling that method from command-button and see if it works?